# Force devdemon channel files to open pdf's in a browser

Tags: devdemon, channel-files

I need to make channel files locked url to open pdf's in the browser rather than prompting users to download. I can't see this as an option, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the obfuscated link provided by the locked URL doesn't have a file type. So this means Google isn't reading it and it can't be shown as a web page. If you want the browser to show it like a web page you have to use the regular url.

Brad

Comment: OK, thanks. I wrote a little plugin which does just what i need. I don't want to expose the path to files so have the file links pointing to my plugin.

Comment: Hey @BillyMedia any chance you would share the plugin? I'm stuck in the same situation...thanks!